# Jacobian in path-integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, integration

I am reading Inomata's "Alternative Exact-Path-Integral Treatment of the Hydrogen Atom" and I think I've worked too long because I got stuck near the end and cant for the life of me figure it out.

Could someone kindly explain the magic eqn (18)? I am thinking its just changing variables and inserting the jacobian in there, but after trying for quite a while I cant reproduce it. Some insight into 19 would also be appreciated.[image]